# Is Spring Roo only for making the skeleton of a site?

Tags: java, spring-roo

After many problems, I have finally set up Roo with a simple example.

Now I just want to know how far should one go with Roo.

I mean likes fields, classes, everything can be done through the Roo shell.

Now, for example, I have 15 classes in my project.  I'm confused - to what point should I make classes with the Roo shell and when should I leave Roo and start working like normal?

Also, Roo has its own GUI and layout design. Can we change that also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use ROO to generate the models, controllers and the scaffold, then I strip out a large chunk of the Scaffold so that I can put my own components in there and some of the controllers I still need to write by hand.
When you reach the point where you have an interface generated by ROO, start hacking away and only use ROO to add new domain models.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try Telosys Tools, it has been design to generate a full web application from an existing database.

It’s more flexible than Spring Roo, you can customize the model and the generator templates

The tutorial for code generation with Spring MVC and Spring Data is here : https://sites.google.com/site/telosystutorial/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jan.  The Roo Scaffold application is just that:  a structure that you can use to build your own application around, but that isn't something you'd like to expose as a client in its own right.  So far I have used Roo when creating or changing the data model, and have allowed it to manage and modify a lot of the code that is necessary for interacting with the data model.  But any work I'm doing outside of the model I do myself.

My advice: use Roo where its strength is, and then do the rest by hand.